# vendor folder not used with 'go build'

Tags: github, go

I'm using go-1.7 in MacOS Sierra.

My project is inside my *$GOPATH/src* folder and has a *vendor* folder inside with all its dependencies.

and I'm using the dependencies like this inside my code:

```
import (
"github.com/google/go-github/github"
)
```

Now if I run `go build` i get the message that all my dependencies I use could not be found inside the $GOROOT and $GOPATH on the other and adding "vendor" to my code is working:

```
import (
"vendor/github.com/google/go-github/github"
)
```

But as far as I understood it should be possible to to like in the first code snipped.

ah FYI there are no symlinks etc.

Comment: Is your code directly in $GOPATH/src? Than that is the problem. Even with the vendor directory your code must still be in it's own subdirectory inside the $GOPATH (e.g. $GOPATH/src/foo)

Comment: its in a subfolder ($GOPATH/src/project)

Comment: `go build` should list the paths it searched. One of them should have '(vendor tree)' after the path. In your case it should list '$GOPATH/src/project/vendor/github.com/google/go-github/github'. If not, you vendor directory is not recognized by the go tool.

Comment: I know that it lists them but only $GOPATH and $GOROOT are listed... so yes it doesnt recognize my vendor folder and thats what I'm trying to fix ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok found the problem:

My MacOS File System is Case Insensitive but it looks like the go tools cant handle that... 
fixed my $GOPATH and now it works like it should...

Comment: Could you explain more in detail the problem and the fix please ? This might be helpful for other people.

Comment: Well, i simply changed the $GOPATH inside my shell config file... so instead  of export GOPATH=/projects/go I changed it to export GOPATH=/Projects/go because thats was the acctual folder name..

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. On my mac I did a `cd directory/to/my/gopath` then ran build which broke since the directory was `Directory/to/my/gopath`.

Answer (score 14):

From go 1.12+ go modules is the new way of handling dependencies.

- To fix dependency version `go mod init`
- To bring modules in vendor folder `go mod vendor`
- To build from the vendor directory `go build -mod vendor -o output`

Answer (score 2):

you could use `echo $GOPATH` in your terminal to see your path of golang in my case is `/home/gujarat/golang`. this is the default path without `src` path.

So from here all your packages and dependencies are inside `src` in `$GOPATH`. for example here is some packages that I used in my project.

```
"fmt"
"github.com/myproject/lol/src/config" // notice the first github.com
"gopkg.in/redis.v4" // notice the gopkg.in
"log"
```

from the above package you must have all the folder and dependencies copied in your `src` folder. like `github.com` and `gopkg.in` these are the folder that must exist if in `src` root.

and if you cant import your `"github.com/google/go-github/github"` it means that your `github.com` inside your `src` doens't have this folder. hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I got this error and struggled for a while; I update to Go 1.8.3 and was using glide version 0.12.3; and my GOPATH was set as $PWD and glide was installing everything in ./vendor folder;

Finally got the error; **THERE SHOULD BE a src folder under GOPATH and all your workspace should be under this src folder**

It must be in the docs, and in dev machine I set it proper; but missed in Jenkins build

Comment: In fact, it is in the docs already if one looks `go help gopath`